# How do I force element with "display:table" nested in element with "display:table-row" to fill remaining height in MSIE10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

While doing some markup, I've discovered, that MSIE10, actually, does not "understand" what I'm trying to explain to it. Here is a reproduction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*
    {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

html,
body
    {
        display: block;

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

body
    {
        background: #eee;

        display: table;
    }

body > div.header
    {
        background: #aaa;

        display: table-row;

        height: 92px;
    }

body > div.header > div.layout
    {
        background: #666;

        display: table;

        height: inherit;
        width: 100%;
    }

body > div.main
    {
        background: #aaa;

        display: table-row;

        height: 100%;
    }

body > div.main > div.layout
    {
        background: #666;

        display: table;

        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

body > div.main > div.layout > div
    {
        display: table-cell;
    }

div.menu
    {
        background: #fff;
        width: 280px;
    }

div.content
    {
        background: #fff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="layout"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="menu">
        x
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        y
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to force `div.main > div.layout` fill remaining height of body, which works in Chrome, FF, Opera and even Safari. However MSIE ignoring any my attempts to do it. I've tried to use `height: inherit` for it, but it has no effect too. The other option was to use `display: block` and make child elements `div.menu` and `div.content` to have `display: inline-block; height: inherit`, but it also failed: I wasn't able (or just dont know how) to make `div.content` fill remaining width properly.

So here is the question: ***how can I do that ?***

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could see it the other way around, your header seems to have a known height. let's focus on it.

Your problem is that there is no colspan option via CSS. Instead we can use the height of a table-row to lay a container of minus or even height over that space.

Let's try with your header :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLAGI/

**HTML** (replace html5 elemnt with div if you prefer )

```
<header>
  <div> header </div>
</header>
<main>
  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>
  <article>
    article 
  </article>
</main>
```

And **CSS** to try.

```
body {
  display:table;
}
header{
  background:green;
  height:92px;
}
header > div {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:inherit;
  height:inherit;
}
main {
  display:table-row;
}
/* sizing and cells*/
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
aside {
  width:200px;
  display:table-cell;
}
main {
  height:100%;
  background:gray;
}
article {
  background:yellow;  
  display:table-cell;
}
```

**Your header will not be resized from its content**, it needs a value set in CSS that first child can inherit to use.

Comment: you can download test files here : http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/eLAGI/ (html and css separate in folders)